# c# gRPC and WindowsIdentity

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core, grpc

All, I’m considering moving a WCF client-server system to gRPC (as recommended due to WCF end of life)

However, this looks tricky, as I can’t find a gRPC equivalence of this server side call to:

OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name;

Which is used to set up the WCF session and work out privaledges from a back end DB.

This is a major issue/stopper :(

The server is a c# windows service.

We’re a 100% windows shop, so I’m not bothered about cross platform portability.

Comment: Are you using Windows Auth?  Windows Auth can't be used with gRPC.  You'd probably want to consider certs instead.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/security

Comment: OperationContext is a class in the .net framework, and there is no such class in core. In core we can use HttpContext, for more information about "Access HttpContext in ASP.NET Core", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2